# Insert navigation bar in Beamer presentation with Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, presentation

I am trying to make Beamer presentation in R Markdown, you can see how code begin below :

```
---
title: "Test presentation"  
author:   
  - Loana  
institute:   
  - Supervised by   
  - University  
date: Academic year 2017-2018  
output:   
  beamer_presentation:  
    incremental: false  
    theme: "Frankfurt"  
    colortheme: "beaver"  
    toc: true   
    slide_level: 5
    keep_tex: true
header-includes: 
- \AtBeginSubsection{} 
---
```

This code give output like pic below
[image]

But my intention is to have navigation bar in right corner of slide, so can anybody help me how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following your desired output?

[image]

If so, create a file `header.tex` with the following contents (taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35637/181010)

```tex
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
  \vskip-9.75ex%
  \else%
  \vskip-7ex%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
  \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,%
                         leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
  \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}%
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \hskip1em\usebeamercolor[fg]{navigation symbols dimmed}%
}
\makeatother
```

Then add the header to the yaml of your `.Rmd` as:

```
---
title: "Test presentation"  
author:   
  - Loana  
institute:   
  - Supervised by   
  - University  
date: Academic year 2017-2018  
output:
  beamer_presentation:  
    incremental: false  
    theme: "Frankfurt"  
    colortheme: "beaver"  
    toc: true   
    slide_level: 5
    keep_tex: true
header-includes: 
  - \AtBeginSubsection{} 
  - \input{header.tex}
---
```

Comment: I tried but I still have problem. So now my problem is how to create and input into R Markdown {header.tex}

Comment: Did you put `header.tex` in the same folder as the main `.Rmd` file?

Comment: I already and code is executed but nothing is happened with slide. Maybe I have some additional problem

Comment: If you change the contents of the slide (for example, change the author name) and re-run does the outputted .pdf change?

Comment: Nothing is happen. Thank you anyway I will try to manage on different way

Comment: You're welcome. maybe try remove the current pdf and start again? The above does work for me

Comment: I tried, but nothing is the same. Actually my goal is to have pdf like this example but I will continue to explore :) https://www.overleaf.com/project/5f8997dc3d5444000160a685